# How to change a particular value in a table with Google Sheets Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to google script and after hours it seems I'm very close, but finally I ask for your help.

My table contains 6 columns but more than 1000 rows. I want to select a particular row and want to change one of the 6 columns.
I managed to find the row I was looking for, but now I get stuck when updating a value because I don't know the range of the 'filtered result'.

This I have so far... please also find the comments in the code:

```js
function useDataRange () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "PlanningX";
  var rows = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname).getDataRange().getValues();

  var filteredRows = rows.filter(function(row) {
    var ccTitle = row[2]; // my costcenter 
    var mmMonth = row[1]; // my month by name
    var searchTitle = '03.008 Bahntickets';
    var searchMonth = 'April';
    
    // because of my data structure I got 1 result (row) after this IF conditions

    if (ccTitle === searchTitle && mmMonth === searchMonth) {
      return row
    }
  })
  Logger.log(filteredRows); // yep,  this works as expected, I got only 1 row back.

  /* -----------------------------------------------------------
    Now I try to change the value in this row at column 4 to another value
    but because I don't know the range, I cannot set the value */

  filteredRows.forEach(function(row) {
    var cell = (row[4]) // this is the row number (4) I try to update
    var cell = newValue;
    var newValue = 'MY NEW VALUE'; // now I get stuck

  })

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following script,

```
filteredRows.forEach(function(row) {
  var cell = (row[4]) // this is the row number (4) I try to update
  var cell = newValue;
  var newValue = 'MY NEW VALUE'; // now I get stuck

})
```

If you want to replace the value of column "E" with a value of "MY NEW VALUE", how about the following modification?

#### From :

```
filteredRows.forEach(function(row) {
  var cell = (row[4]) // this is the row number (4) I try to update
  var cell = newValue;
  var newValue = 'MY NEW VALUE'; // now I get stuck

})
```

#### To:

```
filteredRows.forEach(function (row) {
  var newValue = 'MY NEW VALUE';
  row[4] = newValue;
});
```

or

```
var updatedValues = filteredRows.map(row => {
  var newValue = 'MY NEW VALUE';
  row[4] = newValue;
  return row;
});
```

- By this modification, column "E" of each `row` in `filteredRows` replace with `MY NEW VALUE`.

### Added:

From your following reply and your added image,

> I just attached a screenshot of my table. For example: I want to change the value at column E at line #263 say from 154 to 200.

how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function useDataRangedd() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "PlanningX";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var range = sheet.getRange("A5:E" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var rows = range.getValues();
  rows.forEach(row => {
    if (row[1] == 'April' && row[2] == '03.008 Bahntickets') {
      row[4] = 200;
    }
  });
  range.setValues(rows);
}
```

or, as another approach, how about the following script?

```js
function useDataRangedd() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "PlanningX";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var range = sheet.getRange("A5:E" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var rows = range.getValues();
  var ranges = rows.reduce((ar, row, i) => {
    if (row[1] == 'April' && row[2] == '03.008 Bahntickets') {
      ar.push(`E${i + 5}`);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue(200);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back! Unfortunately that doesn't work. I think I have to use something like setValues([newValue]) but this tasks needs a getRange(xxx) and I don't know the given Range.

Comment: @Roman Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, in this case, it is required to know the sample input and output situations you expect. Because I cannot understand your expected situation from `I think I have to use something like setValues([newValue]) but this tasks needs a getRange(xxx) and I don't know the given Range.`. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Roman I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill and if you can cooperate to resolve your issue. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Of course I will try: My table contains a value in column E. I want to WRITE a new value in column E (substitute). To get the correct row to write, my first lines of code can find this row.

Comment: @Roman Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your actual expected result from `My table contains a value in column E. I want to WRITE a new value in column E (substitute). To get the correct row to write, my first lines of code can find this row.`. can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I just attached a screenshot of my table. 
For example: I want to change the value at column E at line #263 say from 154 to 200.

Comment: @Roman Thank you for replying. From your following reply and your added image, I added one more modified script. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike. The 2nd Code Snippet works like a charm, just perfect!